# How to use React to show a dialog when api detect HTTP Status is 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am new to web development.I want to use React to show a dialog when the HTTP status is 401.How to trigger App page to show dialog when the status is 401

Comment: You need to show us an example in which you have tried something. There are several tutorials online regarding how to make an HTTP request and how to access the HTTP response status code. From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) you can see how to access the HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use `useState` to contain the dialog status (default value is `false`).
The value is used by DialogComponent (Example: From any library as MUi, Antd,...)
In the API function, you can use try/catch in order to catch the error status. Then you use `setState` to update the dialog's state.

Example:

```
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    
    const getData = async() => {
       try {
         await getDataFromApi()
       } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response.status === 401) {
          // do something ...
          setIsOpen(true)
        }
       }
    }

    return (
      <div>
       // components...
       <DialogComponent isOpen={isOpen}/>
      </div>
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to make an HTTP request and how to access/check the HTTP response status code:

```js
async function makeRequest() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://randomlink.com/api/');

        if (response.status === 401) {
            // open modal
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

await makeRequest();
```